# Dropdown menu in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I have tried to build a dropdown button and a menu with it, where the value will be selected from the dropdown menu. The code is as below:

```
String valueChoose;
 List listItem = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

DropdownButton(
 hint: Text('Associate'),
 dropdownColor: Colors.white,
 icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
 iconSize: 20.0,
 style: TextStyle(
 fontSize: 22.0,
 color: Colors.black,
 ),
 value: valueChoose,
 onChanged: (newValue) {
 setState(() {
 valueChoose = newValue;
 });
 },
 items: listItem.map((valueItem){
 return DropdownMenuItem(
  value: valueItem,
  child: Text(valueItem),
  );
  }).toList(),
 ),
```

The error I'm facing is in the set state, where I've assigned `newValue` to the `valueChoose`.

```
A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.
```

That is the error showing up for the newValue assinged in the set state. Please help regarding this, thanks in advance!

Below is the code, including the AlertDailog:

```
  class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
   }
    
   class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
   String ? valueChoose;
    List listItem = [
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
      ];
     void assignPopup(BuildContext context) {
     var alertDialog = AlertDialog(
      content: 
          Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
          Row(
          children:[
          Container(
          child: Text(
          'Action',
          ),
          ),
          ]
          ),
          Row(
          children:[
          Container(
          child: Card(
          elevation: 5.0,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Please add any comments',
          ),
          ),
          ),
          ),
          ]
          ),
          Row(
          children:[
          Container(
          child: Text(
          'Assign To',
           ),
           ),
           ]
           ),
           Row(
           children: [
           Container(
           child: Card(
           elevation: 5.0,
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
           ),
           child: DropdownButton<String>(
           hint: Text('Associate'),
           dropdownColor: Colors.white,
           icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
           iconSize: 40.0,
           style: TextStyle(
           fontSize: 18.0,
           color: Colors.black,
           ),
           value: valueChoose,
           onChanged: (newValue) {
           setState(() {
           valueChoose = newValue;
           });
           },
           items: listItem.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((valueItem){
           return DropdownMenuItem(
           value: valueItem,
           child: Text(valueItem),
            );
            }).toList(),
            ),
            ),
            ),
            ],
            ),
           ],
          ),
          );
          showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return alertDialog;
           }
          );
        }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
              ...
              ...
         Container(
         child: TextButton(
         onPressed: (){
         assignPopup(context);
         },
         child: Text(
         'Assign',
          ),
          ),
          ),
         );
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the data that you provided I have created a example where I have used the alertdialog and inside it there is a drop down

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String valueChoose;
  List listItem = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

  void assignPopup(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              content: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Row(children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        'Action',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                  Row(children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 5.0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Please add any comments',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                  Row(children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        'Assign To',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 5.0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          child: DropdownButton<String>(
                            hint: Text('Associate'),
                            dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                            iconSize: 40.0,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            value: valueChoose,
                            onChanged: (newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                valueChoose = newValue;
                              });
                            },
                            items: listItem
                                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((valueItem) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                value: valueItem,
                                child: Text(valueItem),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          });
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              assignPopup(context);
            },
            child: Text(
              'Assign',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So here in order to change dropdown value you have to use the StatefulBuilder which will change your dropdown value. you can check the above example and make changes as per your needs.

Please run the code to check the desired output.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: That is the same way I've used it, within the stateful builder as you said, but I don't realize where the slip is.

Comment: can you please add the code that you have used using the statefullBuilder

Comment: from the code that you have posted it runs perfectly, what problem you are having can you describe please.

Comment: @yaminir please check the code, and let me know if you face any errors.

Comment: I have made edits like you have asked, along with the class and the popup widget, please go through and check. The dropdown list is still not been able to select dynamically.

Comment: hey @yaminir i have removed the previous code and edited the new code that you have added please check.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the types of `DropdownButton` and that `map`

```
String? valueChoose;
  List listItem = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

DropdownButton<String>(
            hint: Text('Associate'),
            dropdownColor: Colors.white,
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            iconSize: 20.0,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 22.0,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            value: valueChoose,
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              setState(() {
                valueChoose = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: listItem.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((valueItem) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: valueItem,
                child: Text(valueItem),
              );
            }).toList(),
          )
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to clear the error and run it. But there is a problem, the items that I select from the dropdown is not working dynamically. I need to close the popup and reopen it to see the changes. Can you please help on that?

Comment: I didnt get your point, but it is working fine for me.

Comment: I have used this dropdown within the `AlertDialog` popup. So, when I select the item in the dropdown, I should reopen the Dialog box every time to see the changes in the selection.

Comment: can you share the code of your AlertDialog?

Comment: Move the ```DropdownButton``` or the whole ```AlertDialog``` into a separate ```Stateful``` or ```Stateless``` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Declare variables outside the `build` method.

```
 String? valueChoose;
  List listItem = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
```

Inside the build method add the `Dropdown` widget, So the complete state class code would look like this,

```
class _DropdownViewState extends State<DropdownView> {
  String? valueChoose;
  List listItem = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      hint: Text('Associate'),
      dropdownColor: Colors.white,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
      iconSize: 20.0,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 22.0,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      value: valueChoose,
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          valueChoose = newValue;
        });
      },
      items: listItem.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((valueItem){
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: valueItem,
          child: Text(valueItem),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```